# H2 database - implicit timestamp conversion

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have a timestamp column in my H2 database which contains data such as `2015-01-14 21:32:29`, however when I retrieve those values by JSTL, I get the following value: `1421261300000`. Can any one help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code (trimmed down as much as possible, of course) are you using to store and retrieve it? Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is currently storing the time as a UTC time (number of milliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970). If you want it stored in a human readable format, you need to specify a user datatype. Fortunately this has already been done by the Jadira User Types library for Hibernate.

Assuming that your class looks a little something like this:

```
//other class fields declared above here
@Column
private Date theDate;
```

You only need to import the Jadira types library from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype) and then change your `Date` type to a JodaTime/Java 8 `DateTime` object. If you aren't using Java 8, import JodaTime from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time).

When you add the following annotation, Hibernate should automatically store your field as a human readable timestamp.

```
//Other class fields declared above here
@Column
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime theDate;
```

Violá your timestamp is now human readable.